# Format list of strings using Jinja2 filter with Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list similar to

```yaml
my_apps:
  - bootstrap-client
  - theme-client
  - engine-client
```

I want to turn this array into a string similar to

```
$LOCAL_DIR/bootstrap-client-*.war $LOCAL_DIR/theme-client-*.war $LOCAL_DIR/engine-client-*.war
```

Is this possible using Jinja2 filters? In a Ansible template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Ansible filter [`regex_replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) in combination with the [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map) and [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join) filters to achieve this.

So so have to regex match the whole list item `^(.*)$` and back reference it using `\\1` in your replacement.

Giving you:

```yaml
"{{ my_apps | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '$LOCAL_DIR/\\1-*.war' ) | join(' ') }}"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_apps | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', '$LOCAL_DIR/\\1-*.war' ) | join(' ') }}" 
      vars:
        my_apps:
          - bootstrap-client
          - theme-client
          - engine-client
```

This yields:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: $LOCAL_DIR/bootstrap-client-*.war $LOCAL_DIR/theme-client-*.war $LOCAL_DIR/engine-client-*.war

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```